# Update test cases in TFS2015 that are associated with unit tests

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs, mstest, tfs-2015

I got build definition in tfs2015 with two steps, in second one i'm running unit tests:

[image]

Is there a way to update test cases in tfs that are associated(associated automation) with those unit tests?

[image]

I.e. mark test cases as passed if associated unit test passed in latest build.
Right now after build my test cases are marked active, no matter if corresponding unit tests passed or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is bo way to update Teat Cases without using Microsoft Test Manager. You would use the old Test Agent / Controller model.

In TFS 2015/2017 there is a new model that does not involve Test Cases: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/08/02/traceability-with-continuous-testing/

[image]

In the Build results view of the Test Cases you can directly associate the test result with a Requirement (User Story/PBI). Once done all future results will be associated with the same Requirement.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/report/widget-catalog#requirements-quality-widget

You can then add the "Requirements Quality" widget on the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can run test through Run Functional Tests step/task. With this step/task, you can specify test plan and test suite that contains automated test cases.

[image]

Article: [Executing Automated tests in Build vNext using Test Plan, Test Suites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/executing-automated-tests-in-build-vnext-using-test-plan-test-suites/)